# Wordpress url for homepage

Tags: wordpress, url, hosting, vps

is here some option, how can I set url for homepage?

Default is http://domain.com. I want domain.com/magazine/ but just for homepage not for other pages (domain.com/magazine/post/, …) It is effect if I try change WP_HOME…

I don’t have wordpress instalation in subdirectory but I have my reasons for this.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to solve this problem

**Method 1:** Use RedirectMatch with htaccess.

Add the following sentence to your htaccess file:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/$ /magazine/
```

Demo:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RedirectMatch 301 ^/$ /magazine/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

**Method 2:** Login wordpress and go to Settings > Reading.

In section "Front page displays" tick the box "A static page (select below)" and click select Front page: magazine

Hope to help you.